# How can I save to file label() output in R?

Tags: r

There is a list of objects, in data variable.

I call (library: Hmisc):

`label(data)`

Output:

```
$SubsID
NULL

$SubsID_RN
NULL

$responseid
NULL

$Wave
2014   2013   2012 
"2014" "2013" "2012" 

$Country
 Hong Kong         Taiwan          Chile      Singapore    New Zealand 
      "46"           "45"           "44"           "43"           "42" 
   Finland   Saudi Arabia         Israel    Netherlands        Belgium 
      "41"           "40"           "39"           "38"           "37" 
   Tunisia   South Africa       Malaysia         Mexico         Canada 
      "36"           "35"           "34"           "33"           "32" 
  Portugal    Switzerland       Columbia      Venezuela         Brazil 
      "31"           "30"           "29"           "28"           "27" 
 Argentina            UAE         Turkey          India        Austria 
      "26"           "25"           "24"           "23"           "22" 
     Japan          China      Australia        Ireland     UK (Welsh) 
      "21"           "20"           "19"           "18"           "17" 
  Thailand    South Korea         Russia         Poland Czech Republic 
      "16"           "15"           "14"           "13"           "12" 
   Hungary         Greece         Norway        Denmark         Sweden 
      "11"           "10"            "9"            "8"            "7" 
     Spain        Germany          Italy         France            USA 
       "6"            "5"            "4"            "3"            "2" 
        UK 
       "1"
```

And a want to write it to file. With this command:

```
write.table(label(data), "labels.txt")
```

And i get an error.

```
Error in data.frame(SubsID = NULL, SubsID_RN = NULL, responseid = NULL,  : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 46, 3, 9, 18, 13, 50, 5, 23, 2,
12, 7,    8, 4, 6, 20, 11, 10
```

Any idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write the printed output from an R function to a file, then use sink:

```
 > sink("output.txt")
 > label(data) # nothing appears
 > sink()  # reset output to screen
```